# How we add the querying string in the URL dynamically in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i want to add the query string in the URL dynamically how could it possible on client side. I can to it through location.href and response.redirect but i don`t want to do with this

Thanks

Comment: Your question is very very ambiguous. Add more details and if possible the code.

Comment: in all hyperlink u need to add same query string?

Comment: Whats the problem in location.href ? What do you want to achieve ?

Comment: i have to filter the data based on some search criteria so that user able to see the filtration  on the URL for more details you can see the following http://www.carwale.com/new/search.aspx#budget=1&budget=2&budget=3&budget=4&budget=5&budget=6&budget=7&budget=8&budget=9&make=49&make=22&make=47&make=2&make=5&make=7&make=4&make=16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [jQuery BBQ](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/) library, specifically the [`jQuery.param.queryString`](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/docs/files/jquery-ba-bbq-js.html#jQuery.param.querystring%28build_url%29) method.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.TestClass').attr(function () {
        return $(this).href() + '?test1=a&test2=b';
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the filtration in the URL than you will have to use location.href like:

location.href = "yourpage.aspx?filter1=" + val

but if showing the filtration is not a requirement than you can send a JSON call and show the filtered data to the user.